# sending Image from Socket server (java) to socket client (python)

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am trying to send an image from Socket server (Java) to socket client (Python) but the received image in client has an incorrect size and does not open. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Server (Java):

```
...
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read (new File("c:\\tmp\\File.png"));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
...
```

Client (Python):

```
try:
   client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect( host , port )
    data = client_socket.recv( 1024 )
    fp = open ( path, "wb" )
    while data:
        data = client_socket.recv( 1024 )
        if data:
            if not data: break
            fp.write  ( data )
            fp.flush()
        fp.close()
        client_socket.close()
except:
    print "could not connect to %s:%s " %( host, port
```

Comment: use base64 encoding to transfert

Comment: Thank you Could you please explain more

Comment: You must know how many data you will sent to be sure to receive all of them. In java, get your image size (called 's' for example) before transfert, first send the size 's' to the python client, then read 's' next data. Else you can use a end delimiter for your transfert and reading datas while you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your image to a base64 string (Java), then transfert the string and get back to the image data (python).

In java, to get Image from base64 string:

```
public static Image image(String base64Img) {
 byte[] b = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Img);
 ByteArrayInputStream s = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
 return new Image(s);
}
```